# Count number of different possible $3 \times 3$ grids.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a square $3 \times 3$ grid of non-negative integers.  For each row $i$ the sum of the integers is set to be $r_i$.  Similarly for each column $j$ the sum of integers in that column is set to be $c_j$.

I would like to know how many different possible assignments of integers to the grid there are.  Is it possible to give an exact number?

Comment: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~barvinok/linalg.pdf

Comment: @zwim I updated the question to make it more specific and hopefully easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may suppose that we are given six non-negative integers $r_1,r_2,r_3,c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that
$$r_1\le r_2\le r_3,\qquad c_1\le c_2\le c_3,\qquad r_1+r_2+r_3=c_1+c_2+c_3$$

Let $N_{(i,j)}$ be the number in $(i,j)$ as follows :

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

where
$$r_1=N_{(1,1)}+N_{(1,2)}+N_{(1,3)},\quad r_2=N_{(2,1)}+N_{(2,2)}+N_{(2,3)},\quad r_3=N_{(3,1)}+N_{(3,2)}+N_{(3,3)}$$
$$c_1=N_{(1,1)}+N_{(2,1)}+N_{(3,1)},\quad c_2=N_{(1,2)}+N_{(2,2)}+N_{(3,2)},\quad c_3=N_{(1,3)}+N_{(2,3)}+N_{(3,3)}$$

---

First, let us consider $N_{(1,1)}$.

We see that $N_{(1,1)}$ has to satisfy $0\le N_{(1,1)}\le \min(r_1,c_1)$, and that $N_{(1,1)}$ can be every integer satisfying $0\le N_{(1,1)}\le \min(r_1,c_1)$.

Next, let us consider $N_{(1,2)}$ and $N_{(2,1)}$.

We see that $N_{(1,2)}$ has to satisfy $0\le N_{(1,2)}\le \min(r_1-N_{(1,1)},c_2)$, and that $N_{(1,2)}$ can be every integer satisfying $0\le N_{(1,2)}\le \min(r_1-N_{(1,1)},c_2)$ where we note that $$r_1-N_{(1,1)}\ge r_1-\min(r_1,c_1)\ge 0,\qquad c_2-N_{(1,2)}\ge c_2-\min(r_1-N_{(1,1)},c_2)\ge 0$$

Similarly, we see that $N_{(2,1)}$ has to satisfy $0\le N_{(2,1)}\le \min(r_2,c_1-N_{(1,1)})$, and that $N_{(2,1)}$ can be every integer satisfying $0\le N_{(2,1)}\le \min(r_2,c_1-N_{(1,1)})$ where we note that $$c_1-N_{(1,1)}\ge c_1-\min(r_1,c_1)\ge 0,\qquad r_2-N_{(2,1)}\ge r_2-\min(r_2,c_1-N_{(1,1)})\ge 0$$

Now $N_{(1,1)},N_{(1,2)},N_{(2,1)}$ are determined. Then, $N_{(1,3)},N_{(3,1)}$ are determined as follows :
$$N_{(1,3)}=r_1-N_{(1,1)}-N_{(1,2)},\qquad N_{(3,1)}=c_1-N_{(1,1)}-N_{(2,1)}$$

Finally, let us consider the remaining $2\times 2$-grids.

Using the idea of **zwim**'s answer, we see that there are 
$$Part(\min(c_2-N_{(1,2)},c_3-N_{(1,3)},r_2-N_{(2,1)},r_3-N_{(3,1)}),2)$$
possible grids for the remaining $2\times 2$-grids where $Part(x,n)$ is the number of partitions of $x$ into $n$ non-negative integers.

Here, we note that both $c_3-N_{(1,3)}$ and $r_3-N_{(3,1)}$ are non-negative since
$$\begin{align}&c_3-N_{(1,3)}=c_3-(r_1-N_{(1,1)}-N_{(1,2)})\ge c_3-r_1\ge 0\\\\&r_3-N_{(3,1)}=r_3-(c_1-N_{(1,1)}-N_{(2,1)})\ge r_3-c_1\ge 0\end{align}$$
where we used that $$c_3=\frac{c_3+c_3+c_3}{3}\ge \frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{3}=\frac{r_1+r_2+r_3}{3}\ge\frac{r_1+r_1+r_1}{3}=r_1$$$$r_3=\frac{r_3+r_3+r_3}{3}\ge\frac{r_1+r_2+r_3}{3}=\frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{3}\ge \frac{c_1+c_1+c_1}{3}=c_1$$

Since $Part(x,2)=x+1$, we see that there are
$$\min(c_2-j,c_3-r_1+i+j,r_2-k,r_3-c_1+i+k)+1$$
possible grids for the remaining $2\times 2$-grids where $i:=N_{(1,1)},j:=N_{(1,2)},k:=N_{(2,1)}$.

---

*Conclusion* :

When we are given six non-negative integers $r_1,r_2,r_3,c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that
$$r_1\le r_2\le r_3,\qquad c_1\le c_2\le c_3,\qquad r_1+r_2+r_3=c_1+c_2+c_3$$

the number of possible grids is given by

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\min(r_1,c_1)}\sum_{j=0}^{\min(r_1-i,c_2)}\sum_{k=0}^{\min(r_2,c_1-i)}(\min(c_2-j,c_3-r_1+i+j,r_2-k,r_3-c_1+i+k)+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for $3\times 3$-grids, here is what I found for $2\times 2$:

We need to have $\sum_j c_j=\sum_i r_i$ else there is no solution.

*Rem: here we work in $\mathbb N$, with zero included, all numbers invoked are non-negative.*

- **For $1\times 1$-grids there is obviously $1$ possible grid.**
- **For $2\times 2$-grids there are $Part(\min(c_1,c_2,r_1,r_2),2)$ possible grids.**

where $Part(x,n)$ is the number of partitions of $x$ into $n$ integers.

For instance let examine the following matrix

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c}\hline
. & . & 7\\
. & ? & 5\\\hline
9 & 3 & \end{array}$

$3$ is the minimum entry here, it can be partitioned $4$ different ways $[0+3],\ [1+2],\ [2+1],\ [3+0]$

If we select $0,1,2$ or $3$ for the value of the cell marked "$?$" then this value is free to set because it is smaller than $5$ the next minimum entry.

From the choice of the value in this cell, all other values are decided (I let you experiment with that, to convince yourself it is the case).

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c}\hline 4 & 3 & 7\\ 5 & \color{blue}0 & 5\\\hline 9 & 3 & \end{array}
\qquad\begin{array}{|c|c|c}\hline 5 & 2 & 7\\ 4 & \color{blue}1 & 5\\\hline 9 & 3 & \end{array}
\qquad\begin{array}{|c|c|c}\hline 6 & 1 & 7\\ 3 & \color{blue}2 & 5\\\hline 9 & 3 & \end{array}
\qquad\begin{array}{|c|c|c}\hline 7 & 0 & 7\\ 2 & \color{blue}3 & 5\\\hline 9 & 3 & \end{array}$

So the number of possible grids is equal to the number of ways of partitioning $3$ into two numbers.

I suspect that for $3\times 3$-grids, $Part(x,3)$ should be involved.

---

From code golf:

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150012/enumerate-all-possible-grids-of-integers-with-constraints

After some tries, the python one at the end is fastest:

[-> Simulate grids here](https://tio.run/##LU27CsIwFJ3tV2QRkjZF2y4SiX/g0iHLJWDBRC/Ea4mt0KW/XlOVM5wXnNNPw/1J9bJcnWeev2XQYCXqvVCkgyMexNHod14dDcy0a2ypMUna/lR0wxgJgoWOJm6EsugZnQ4uvBwzeTk/kFLc0TWNGxkKQCuK74/EohJLqz1H6seBC5H5Z2RnhsRalW1Wg6uJHd0cb0TKNn1EGtjlDJg3yoJq7AUqlSj7VQvUsvqjth8)

*Modifiy the `Input` field $[ c_1 c_2 c_3 r_1 r_2 r_3 ]$ and then hit the $\blacktriangleright$ button.*

Comment: edit: added a link to automatic generation of 3x3-grids.