# Find a float matrix with given row and column sums and predetermined arbitrary values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Sorry for the naivety and poor exposition of the question but I've been banging my head against this one for way too long and, as you'll be able to tell, math is not my forte.

My problem is similar [to this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969542/find-a-matrix-with-given-row-and-column-sums), with some additional information.

The simple version of it can be stated like so: given an empty matrix with known row and column *equal* sums, find a matrix that satisfies the aforementioned sum constraints. Since there is no constraints for the numbers to be integers, a possible solution can be found using / in position (,), where  is the sum for row ,  the sum for column  and  the total. For instance:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
a & b & 2 \\
c & d & 4 \\
\hline
5 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{array}

gives us:

\begin{array}{cc|c}
1.667 & 0.333 & 2 \\
3.333 & 0.667 & 4 \\
\hline
5 & 1 & 6 \\
\end{array}

So far, so good. Now my actual problem is more complex as arbitrary values are set to 0 in the starting matrix, for instance:

\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & 0 & b & 4 \\
0 & c & d & 8 \\
\hline
4 & 2 & 6 & 12\\
\end{array}

This is where I'm stuck. I can get the columns to add up but then the rows stop adding up, or vice-versa, doing e.g. something like: $r_ic_j/(T-x)$ where $x$ is the column sum corresponding to the 0 value in the row. Note that I would ideally keep with that kind of proportional approach as it fits the real-world scenario behind it best. I've looked into solving this using linear programming but to no avail.

Let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: You just have a system of linear equations.  The non-zero matrix elements are the unknowns and you have one equation for each row, and one for each column.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338323/339790). Just solve over the reals, rather than $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: I assume you know about the _iterative proportional fitting_ algorithm, so I assume the issue is preserving those zero values. The column constraints immediately yield $\,(a=4,\,c=2)\,$ after which the first row constraint yields $\,(b=4-a=0)\,$ and the second yields $\,(d=8-c=6)\,$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
$The standard iterative proportional fitting (IPF) algorithm
in Julia/Matlab looks like

```
function ipf(A,x,y)
   u,v = ones(size(x)...), ones(size(y)...)
   for k = 1:2000
       B = A .* (x*v') ./ ((A*v)*v')
       A = B .* (u*y') ./ (u*(u'*B))
       if norm(A-B) < 1e-6; break; end
   end
   return A
end

A,x,y = [1 0 1; 0 1 1], [4;8],  [4;2;6];

ipf(A,x,y)
 4.0  0.0  0.00133422
 0.0  2.0  5.99867
```

where the $(x,y)$ vectors contain the marginal totals,

 $(u,v)$ are all-ones vectors the same size as $(x,y)$, and

 $A$ is an initial (seed) matrix.

In matrix notation, the algorithm is
$$\eqalign{
x &= \pmatrix{ 4 \\  8},\quad 
y=\pmatrix{ 4 \\  2 \\ 6},\qquad
u=\pmatrix{\o \\ \o},\quad 
v=\pmatrix{\o \\ \o \\ \o}
\\
A_0 &= \pmatrix{\o&0&\o \\ 0&\o&\o} \\ 
B_{k+\o}
 &= \left(\frac{A_k\odot xv^T}{A_k\cdot vv^T}\right) \\
A_{k+\o}
 &= \left(\frac{uy^T\odot B_{k+\o}}{uu^T\cdot B_{k+\o}}\right) \\
}$$
The symbol $\odot$ denotes a Hadamard product, so any zeros in the seed matrix are propagated through each iteration and into the solution.